# Can I move my Xbox 360 to another TV?

Tags: xbox-360

Can I unplug my Xbox 360 from my TV and plug it in to another TV, but still have all my saved data on my Xbox?

I want to move my Xbox 360 to my dad's house, but it is already at my mum's, and I do not know if I can plug it in to my dad's TV and keep all my saves on my Xbox 360.

Answer (score 40):

Yes. You can freely change televisions and retain all your save games.

An xbox saves all its data on its hard drive. In fact, there is no console available that saves any data to the television.

The television is just a tool to display its picture.

Comment: hey thank you so much for answering my question it helps a lot.

Comment: If this has answered your question, please let others know by clicking the green tick to accept it.

Comment: May be worth mentioning the cloud service too

Comment: Dont forget to turn it off before moving it

Answer (score 2):

For any device you connect by a video input (HDMI) to a TV, the TV is a Monitor, just like the monitor of a computer.

In fact, you can plug in the XBox into a computer monitor, and it will work, because a TV is just a computer monitor with lots of fancy gimmicks and a horrible user interface. The reverse is also true, you can take a computer and plug it into a TV, using the TV as the computer monitor.

For some devices, HDMI also delivers sound, and power. Neither of these affect anything like save games on an XBox.

Comment: Although they serve a similar purpose, a TV is not the same as a monitor. Trying to use a large TV as a monitor will quickly cause headaches and sore eyes for most individuals because the pixels are spaced too far apart.

Comment: @FreeAsInBeer You're not supposed to sit closer to it than usual. Using a PC to run a TV is fairly common: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Home_theater_PC

Comment: @FreeAsInBeer when hooked up to an HDMI/DVI/VGA/Composite/etc. source, a TV *is* a monitor. The technical difference (which barely exists these days) is the involvement of a TV tuner.

Comment: @hobbs - a TV does a lot of preprocessing of the images coming through, whether they are from HDMI or otherwise, which results in ~70-80ms worth of lag. This isn't noticable when watching TV, but is noticable when playing games or using a PC through the TV. Most TVs have a 'Game Mode' or other way of disabling this processing, but some (most notably Android-based TVs) don't. That's the difference between a monitor and a TV.

Comment: @Robotnik Except a monitor also does a lot of input pre-processing of the images coming through whether they are from HDMI or otherwise. Most monitors have a 'Game Mode' or other way of disabling this processing. It's really the same thing